# Jenkins drops a letter from file paths

Tags: jenkins, cmake, code-composer

We have a Code Composer Studio (Eclipse) project that uses CMAKE to generate makefiles and build. The project compiles as expected when the project is manually imported onto the Jenkins slave (Win10 x64) and executed from the command line but fails when the build is handled by Jenkins. The failure always follows the same pattern: a singular letter is dropped from the path of an object file. For example, `[Repo directory]/Cockpit_Scaling_and_Exceedance_data.dir` becomes `[Repo direcory]/Cockpit_Scaling_and_Exceedance_ata.dir` and linking fails because it cannot find the referenced object file.

I made sure that there are no differences between the account environment variables and the system environment variables and have also configured the Jenkins Service to use the admin account on the slave instead of SYSTEM in order to get rid of as many differences between Jenkins and the command line as possible.

The project will build successfully using one of our other Jenkins slaves (also Win10 x64), so we know that it's not a Windows 10 issue or a problem with our Jenkins configuration. Since I can't find any differences between the configuration of the two slave machines, I was hoping that someone might be able to suggest somewhere to look for this path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found out why the paths to object files were being mangled, but I did get the project to build successfully on the slave via Jenkins. All I did was change all of my system environment variables into user environment variables. I copy-pasted, so I know that the variables themselves did not change.

I have no idea why this corrected this issue as I had inserted a `whoami` call at the beginning of the build to confirm that Jenkins is indeed running as a user and not System. I guess from this point on all of my environment variables will be specific to a user and not SYSTEM...

EDIT: The problem has returned. I have made no further progress in tracking down the cause behind this issue, but I have found that I do not see this symptom when running the scripts in a bash environment instead of a Windows command prompt. Fortunately for me the scripts have all been written in such a way that they can be run in both environments, so I have had my coworkers use bash instead for them.